# Kivy error, [CRITICAL] [Text ] unable to find any valuable text provider (python 3.6.1) (windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have been trying to use Kivy (1.10.0) in pycharm, when it came to testing the install with:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class TutorialApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello Kivy')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TutorialApp().run()
```

this was also tried with 'Label' in place of 'Button'

I got this when ran in pycharm both times:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Denise\.kivy\logs\kivy_17-08-12_56.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\Denise\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Denise\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
  File "C:\Users\Denise\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Denise\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.
```

The same error occurred in python 3.6.1 shell when typing the following:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
```

or

```
from kivy.uix.button import Lable
```

Please help, how do I get Kivy to run?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy-deps.sdl2 kivy-deps.glew 
pip install kivy-deps.gstreamer 
pip install kivy-deps.angle 
pip install –-upgrade kivy
```

This will solve all that issue

Comment: `ERROR: Invalid requirement: '–-upgrade'`
`pip install --upgrade kivy` no longer works.

Answer (score 5):

In PyCharmm in the Project Interpreter, add all the packages that start with:

> kivy-deps.

With the exclusion of the ones with "dev" in the title

Answer (score 4):

According to the source code

```
if 'KIVY_DOC' not in os.environ:
    if not Label:
        from kivy.logger import Logger
        import sys
        Logger.critical('App: Unable to get a Text provider, abort.')
        sys.exit(1)
```

Make sure you have installed all the dependencies according to [installation guide.](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this problem, then I did this... ( This is for people using pycharm and installed all packages but still not working)

In settings->Project Interpreter ->Green Plus Icon to install package

Then search for "kivy.deps.sdl2", and install.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

refer: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5677#issuecomment-389980378-permalink 
James's answer help me well.
on Windows, it can be "solved" by prepending `%AppData%\Python\share\glew\bin;%AppData%\Python\share\sdl2\bin;` to PATH:

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this error is by creating a virtual environment and running the program on the virtual environment

```
(kivy_venv) C:\Users\musers\PycharmProjects\kivy-projects>python main.py
```