# Kivy error: Unable to get a Text provider, abort

Tags: python, kivy

So i try this code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class FirstKivy(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello Kivy!")

FirstKivy().run()
```

And got this `error`:

> [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in
>   C:\Users\raviv.kivy\logs\kivy_19-04-17_45.txt [INFO   ] [Kivy
>   ] v1.10.1 [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec
>   23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] [INFO   ] [Factory
>   ] 194 symbols loaded [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex,
>   img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
>   [CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider.
>   sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be
>   found.   File
>   "C:\Users\jim\csv_file\lib\site-packages\kivy\core__init__.py",
>   line 59, in core_select_lib
>       fromlist=[modulename], level=0)   File "C:\Users\jim\csv_file\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py",
>   line 12, in 
>       from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,
>
> pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'   File
>   "C:\Users\jim\csv_file\lib\site-packages\kivy\core__init__.py",
>   line 59, in core_select_lib
>       fromlist=[modulename], level=0)   File "C:\Users\jim\csv_file\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
>
> [CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.

So i found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655558/kivy-error-critical-text-unable-to-find-any-valuable-text-provider-python) and install all that mentioned:

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew 
pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer 
pip install kivy.deps.angle 
pip install –-upgrade kivy
```

And still got this `error`

Comment: Do you have more than on version of python installed? You need to install Kivy for each version of Python. Try `python -m pip install ...` for each of your installs above.

Comment: How do i check this ? if i type inside cmd python this return Python 3.7.2

Comment: It looks like your error is with Python 3.7.2, so the problem is not likely to be kivy installed under the wrong python.

Comment: Any suggestions how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

try either

```
pip install kivy.deps.glew
```

or

```
pip install kivy.deps.angle
```

Remove one to see if the error changes; i'd imagine its angle. I had a similar problem with a grahics card driver.You also don't need gstreamer (right now)

Comment: What I mean is remove one.

Comment: Or try and directly installing PIL.

Comment: Pillow..python library

Comment: Have you tried removing angle or glew? If not try installing PIL directly that's the module error you're getting. It maybe that your python hasn't installed 'correctly' but I don't think so. `pip3 install pillow`

Comment: Also make sure that the python you're using in your IDE isn't in a venv which doesn't using all the dependencies that you require. What IDE are you using? Check the interpreter settings

Comment: Hey everyone, how do I remove angle/gstreamer/glew? I am having the same issue and found this question!

Comment: Remove using pip or you ide might have a UI to remove dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, I solved it by installing PIL (Pillow)
just type

```
pip install Pillow
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem as yours until I wrapped the class inside an if statement. It goes like this:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hey');

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run();
```

Comment: where is the if statement?