# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pillow' on Pycharm (windows 10)

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

I'm following a youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMHK6NDVlCM) that gives an introduction to kivy and apps made in python.

I'm using pycharm and I'm meant to get a text box appear once my script has run. My script:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label
import pillow
import image


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello Kivy')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I've added `import pillow / image` because I found questions on SO that had the same issue I had so I've managed to sort that error and now encountered a new error which I have no idea what to do.

The SO questions:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655558/kivy-error-critical-text-unable-to-find-any-valuable-text-provider-python)

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55733152/kivy-error-unable-to-get-a-text-provider-abort)

[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil)

My Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/MyProject/App test.py", line 4, in <module>
     import pillow
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pillow'
```

I've put `import pillow` at the top and also added the module in pycharm (`file > settings > +`) and on command prompt `pip install pillow` so why is "No module named 'pillow'" appearing?. So what do I have to do for this text box to appear? The youtube video can show what is meant to happen to be more clearer (skip to (9:50)). Thanks

Full Error:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\MyProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/MyProject/App test1.py"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\xxxx\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-06-03_87.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 11:52:54) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\MyProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: Install conda env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out after a few trials and errors after looking at and reading other programmers results that didn't work for me, I managed to find out why it didn't.

I had downloaded Pycharm AND Anaconda and therefore had TWO versions of python on my device. I uninstalled everything  (wasn't a big deal) and then downloaded python 3.7.7 again - retried exact same code and it worked.

Installations:

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
pip install kivy.deps.angle
pip install pygame
pip install kivy
```

all came up "already satisfied" because they were on ONE copy of python - not the one Pycharm was using. So if anyone else has this issue, check to see if you also have more than one version of python on your device as it will cause confusion. To make things easy instead of uninstalling everything (which I should've realized) you could also switch "my project interpreter" to see if that works.

Rookie mistake! - Thanks for the effort of helping to answer this question!

Answer (score 0):

Write this on your terminal :

```
python -m pip install pillow
```

Or:

```
File/Settings/Project: [Your Project Name]/Project Interpreter/ + / Pillow
```

These solutions should work. If they don't you can always ask me on comments. Happy Coding!

Comment: "Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\xxxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (7.0.0)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages."  I'm super confused!

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see in the tutorial you don't need to import pillow.

only these will do.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello Kivy')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

try creating a virtual environment in pycharm and run the following commands in the venv.

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
pip install kivy.deps.angle
pip install pygame
pip install kivy
```

Comment: That was where the problem started...initial error was `"[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort."` Which led me to the SO questions and then this error

Comment: what is the version of python you are using?

Comment: Python 3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 11:52:54) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: I have tried to run the same. and I am able to do so. your issue is mostly with package installation. see my updated answer

Comment: could it be `if __name__ == '__main__'?` I've tried without this and no error occurs. However the text window still does not appear

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__'` tells your program what to run and in what order. you don't need it though but you have to use `MyApp().run()` in order for your app to run.

Comment: Still not solved. No idea what's going on with it. I've edited and copied in the whole error. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215278/discussion-between-vignesh-krishnan-and-pragmatic-learner).

Answer (score 0):

What pillow version you got?

This should work:

`from PIL import Image`

reffering to other question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil#22722950)), this can work on some version so PIL 
`import Image`