# Unable to get Window or Text Provider with Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am very new to the coding and Kivy business. I apologize for my ignorance. To preface this, I think there is something wrong with my PATH. Sometimes modules will never be recognized after I install them with pip, so that may be the issue. Recently, I have transitioned from Sublime Text to Visual Studio 2019. I have tried ALL of the tutorials offered on the internet. I believe the issue is ME and I do not understand what I am doing. Attached are all of the suggestions I have tried:

- https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5677
- [sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found and [CRITICAL] [App] Unable to get a Window, abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482753/sdl2-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-and)
- [Kivy error, [CRITICAL] [Text ] unable to find any valuable text provider (python 3.6.1) (windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655558/kivy-error-critical-text-unable-to-find-any-valuable-text-provider-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gt-qndBYrCQ&feature=youtu.be
- [ImportError: No module named PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil)

I have uninstalled and installed Kivy 4 or 5 times now and in all of these different configurations. If I send ANY dependency through to be downloaded, I guarantee it will tell me that it is already satisfied.

Here is the program:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class FirstKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello World")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    FirstKivy().run()
```

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\wlade\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-05-14_38.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\wlade\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 11:52:54) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\wlade\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\wlade\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\wlade\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Here is the error given to me by Visual Studio

```
  Message=1
  Source=C:\Users\wlade\source\repos\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py
  StackTrace:
  File "C:\Users\wlade\source\repos\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py", line 8, in build
    return Label(text="Hello World")
  File "C:\Users\wlade\source\repos\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py", line 11, in <module>
    FirstKivy().run()
```

Thank you for your patience :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem in my project but I solved it.
 I installed `[kivy-deps.sdl2]` and `[kivy-deps.glew]` package in my project then 
  its started running. 
 I use PyCharm for development tool and I installed the following procedure:

1. Go to `[Settings]`
2. Seltect `[Project]` and `[Project Iterpreter]`
3. Add package using `+ kivy` install package to run:  `[Kivy],[kivy-deps.sdl2]` and `[kivy-deps.glew]`

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you! it looks like Kivy is more cooperative with Pycharm and Conda. I figured I would just uninstall everything that had to do with Python and Kivy and start over. Would definitely recommend if your modules are getting misplaced all the time.